# C# MVC Making html radio buttons in the same line

Tags: c#, html, css, angularjs, radio-button

I'm coding a web page using C# MVC and AngularJS, and i need tomake a horizontal list of radio buttons (and check cuttons) with labels assigned to them. the problem is that they are presented in a vertical list, in every way that I try.

I've tried:

```
<div align="center">
      <label class="col col-20" style="display:inline" align="center"><input id="WeekRad" align="center" type="radio" style="display:inline" ng-model="Week" ng-click="ThisWeek()" />This Week</label>
      <label class="col col-20" style="display:inline" align="center"><input id="DatesRad" align="center" type="radio" style="display:inline" ng-model="Dates" ng-click="BetweenDates()" />Between Dates</label>
</div>
```

I've also tried:

```
 <span>
       <ul>
           <li style="display:inline">
                <label class="col col-20" style="display:inline" align="center"><input id="WeekRad" align="center" type="radio" style="display:inline" ng-model="Week" ng-click="ThisWeek()" />This Week</label>        
             </li>
            <li style="display:inline">
                <label class="col col-20" style="display:inline" align="center"><input id="DatesRad" align="center" type="radio" style="display:inline" ng-model="Dates" ng-click="BetweenDates()" />Between Dates</label>     
             </li>
        </ul>
 </span>
```

I've tried with and without `<span>` and with and without labels, with and without `style="display:inline"` but each time it remained vertical.

Answer (score 0):

Give a width to outer div and place the radio buttons in inside div's.

Play around the width to adjust the alignment.

```
<div align="center" style="width:***px">
<div style="float:left; width:48%">
**radio
</div>
<div style="float:left; width:48%">
**radio
</div>
</div>
```

this should work

Comment: You mean something like this:

<div align="center" style="width:450px">
                <div>
                    <label class="col col-20" style="display:inline" align="center"><input id="WeekRad" align="center" type="radio" style="display:inline"" />Week</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label class="col col-20" align="center"><input id="DatesRad" align="center" type="radio" />Dates </label>
                </div>
             </div>

I've given the outer div small values and big ones, same result.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the soluton:

```
        <div class="row" align="center" style="margin:auto; max-width:300px">
            <div class="col-lg-6" align="center">
                <div class="input-group" align="center">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" align="center">
                        <label class="col col-20" style="display:inline" align="center">
                            <input id="WeekRad" align="center" type="radio" style="display:inline" />This Week
                        </label>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6" align="center">
                <div class="input-group" align="center">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" align="center">
                        <label class="col col-20" style="display:inline" align="center">
                            <input id="DatesRad" align="center" type="radio"/>Between dates
                        </label>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```